# Git doesn't recognize renamed and modified package file

Tags: java, git

I had a java file called `package/old/myfile.java`. I had committed this file through git. I then renamed my package to `new` so my file was in `package/new/myfile.java`.

I now want to commit this file rename (and content changes) to git.

When I do `git status` I get

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    package/old/myfile.java
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       package/new/myfile.java
```

I've tried `add`ing the new and `rm`ing the old and vice versa, I keep getting

```
$ git status
# On branch develop
# Changes to be committed: 
#        delete:    package/old/myfile.java
#        new file:  package/new/myfile.java
```

I can't do `mv old new` because the old file doesn't exist and so I get `bad source` error.

Is there anything else I can try?

I've tried some of the multiple answers on SO for similar problem, but they haven't worked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [relevant section](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Moving-Files) from the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book) explains this.

> Unlike many other VCS systems, Git doesn’t explicitly track file movement. If you rename a file in Git, no metadata is stored in Git that tells it you renamed the file. However, Git is pretty smart about figuring that out after the fact — we’ll deal with detecting file movement a bit later.

What this means is that if you move a file and then make significant changes git will not know that it was a move.  It will see a file deleted and a new file created because the new file doesn't look like the old one.  To get around this people often `git mv` files, commit the move, and then make changes.  In your situation you can do

```
git reset # Move changes from index to working copy
git checkout package/old/myfile.java # Undo delete
git mv package/old/myfile.java package/new/myfile.java # Move file
```

Answer (score 7):

Move the file back, then commit it, and put the actual move into a separate commit.
Git does not record moves (or renames) as such, but can recognize them afterward based on content. If the content changes, it can't detect the move properly. Therefore it's common practice to split moves and changes into two commits.

Comment: So you mean `checkout` the old file, rename it, commit, add the content updates, commit again?

Comment: No need to check out the old file. You can just move the new file back to its old location (don't forget to update the index), and commit the content changes first. The commit the move afterward.

Comment: when you move the file back, the "delete:" and "new file:" will still remain in the staging area at first. you'll have to add your changes again (e.g. with `git add -A`)

Answer (score 4):

Commands to implement @Nevik Rehnel's suggestion of two commits by rewriting history to move the file before it's edited:

Starting condition:

- your most recent commit includes both a move and modification to a file and `git log --follow newpath` shows the file as newly created in the most recent commit

Steps:

- Tag your current status `git tag working_code`
- Start an interactive rebase to edit the history: `git rebase -i HEAD~2`

  - in the editor that pops up, change "pick" on the first line to "edit", save and exit.
- Your are now editing history just before your commit
- Create the move as its own commit

  - `git mv oldpath newpath`
  - The directory to contain the new file location has to exist; you may have to `mkdir` it first
  - (optionally) Edit the file with any small changes needed to accompany the file rename (ex: in Java: class name and/or package and import lines) - **Avoid making other changes** Git detects these as the same file based on similarity
  - `git add .` and check that `git status` now shows: `renamed: oldpath -> newpath`
  - `git commit -m "Rename oldpath newpath"`
- `git rebase --continue`

  - You should get a conflict on newpath. Restore the file with `git checkout working_code newpath`
  - Complete the rebase: `git rebase --continue`
- Verify that `git log --follow newpath` shows the full history